# C# 6.0 Reflection: Extract the name of backing fields of read-only auto properties

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, c#-6.0

I have a serialization mechanism in place that works on the private fields to determine what should be serialized and what not. The main idea behind the approach is to only serialize the "essence" of the data.

Example:

```
public class Person {
    private readonly string _firstName;
    private readonly string _lastName;

    public C1(string firstName, string lastName) {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get { return _firstName; } }
    public string LastName { get { return _lastName; } }
    public string FullName { get { return _firstName + " " + _lastName; } }
}
```

A serialized example object would then look like this (JSON):

```
{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }
```

As you can see, serializing based on fields ensures that `FullName` is not serialized.

This mechanism was in place for a while now and worked flawlessly. However, with the new read-only auto properties in C# 6.0, the fields have an awkward name like e.g. `<FirstName>k__BackingField`.

Of course, I can update my serialization code to extract the actual property name from the backing field and use that name during serialization. What I want to know: **Is this a robust solution? Or is the naming of the generated backing fields subject to change?**

Note: The reason for this approach is that model classes can remain serialization-agnostic like that. I know that I could also use the [JsonIgnore] attributes to achieve the same, but I don't want to add such attributes to my model classes.

Comment: why don't you just attribute your classes (with your own attribute or one that .net gives you)? i'm guessing that is an internal name that you shouldn't rely on.

Comment: Nobody can ensure that for you.

Comment: @DanielA.White I was just adding a note, see my updated question

Comment: most serialization can use [DataContract] and [DataMember].

Comment: To whomever voted to close this question as "off topic - why isn't this code working". Did you even read a tiny bit of the question???

Comment: "that works on the private fields to determine what should be serialized and what not" Maybe you should explain how you do that - my guess is you rely on a naming convention that doesn't hold for compiler-generated backing fields.  Does it work for read/write auto-implemented properties?

Comment: This isn't at all specific to C# 6. The older `public PropertyType PropertyName { get; set; }` had those same weird field names for the backing field.

Comment: I would  think that the logical conclusion is: *don't use auto properties* if you're going to do this.

Comment: @DStanley It's actually very simple: It just serializes *all* backing fields and uses their name. And I use this mechanism only on value objects (in the sense of OO, not `struct`), so get/set auto properties are never part of those classes (value object are immutable).

Comment: @theDmi Fine, for immutable types you'd still have the same problem before C# 6 with `public PropertyType PropertyName { get; private set; }`, where the property gets set only from the constructor.

Comment: *Is this a robust solution* No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are basing your correlation of backing field to property by a naming convention.  Menaing if you have a private field `_name` and a property `Name` then the field *must* be the backing field for that property.

> Is this a robust solution?

No - a robust solution would be to implement serialization for each type since *only it* knows for certain which fields tie to which property.

> Or is the naming of the generated backing fields subject to change?

This is an implementation detail - MS could decide to change the naming convention however they see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, rather than struggling with the inanities associated wit reflecting over the auto properties, might be to use the [ContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm).

I'm going to omit any examples since the link I provided has 3 practical examples that walk you through the necessaries.